# Have guard skip actions when the git branch has changed

Tags: git, git-branch, guard

I run [guard](http://guardgem.org/), and also switch git branches fairly often. When I switch branches guard runs a whole bunch of actions because many files have changed. Would there be a way for guard to know that files have changed because of a change in git branch, and to skip the actions for that first time after the switch?

Comment: I do not know how your "guard" works, but you may try using a post-checkout hook to disable your `guard` for the next run.

Answer (score 0):

Guard should load pretty fast nowadays, so you can just exit guard while you're switching branches.

Or, You can pause guard - with either the pause command, or a special signal.

Still, this seems useful, so I created this issue: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/828